# Authorize.Net CardPresentVoid not initializing properly

Tags: c#, winforms, authorize.net

This is part two of this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922957/authorize-net-works-in-sandbox-but-not-in-production-code I think this is the same problem but just encase it isn't I wanted to seperate the questions.

As you can see from the photos in the production code the AuthorizeNet.CardPresentVoid object doesn't initialize properly. However, in the sandbox code it does. This is well beyond my years.. Anyone have a clue?

This is the code (minus the real values)

```
 AuthorizeNet.CardPresentVoid cpv = new AuthorizeNet.CardPresentVoid(TransactionID);
 var cpg = new AuthorizeNet.CardPresentGateway(LoginID, TransactionKey, true);    
 AuthorizeNet.IGatewayResponse response = cpg.Send(cpv);
```

Sorry for the photos but apparently if you try and screen shot the info in VS disapears

[image: Production Code]

[image: Sandbox Code]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was pointing at different DLL versions. In my sandbox I was pointing at 1.7.0 and in the production code I was pointing at 1.3.0

When I pointed the production code at 1.7.0 dll it worked fine